# How to loop through urls in a column using download.file()

Tags: r, loops, file, download

I have this `df` from which I need to download all file urls:

```
library(RCurl)

view(df)

    Date       column_1                                                             
    <chr>      <chr>                                                                  
 1  5/1/21     https://this.is.url_one.tar.gz
 2  5/2/12     https://this.is.url_two.tar.gz
 3  7/3/19     https://this.is.url_three.tar.gz
 4  8/3/13     https://this.is.url_four.tar.gz
 5  10/1/17    https://this.is.url_five.tar.gz
 6  12/12/10   https://this.is.url_six.tar.gz
 7  9/9/16     https://this.is.url_seven.tar.gz
 8  4/27/20    https://this.is.url_eight.tar.gz
 9  7/20/15    https://this.is.url_nine.tar.gz
10  8/30/19    https://this.is.url_ten.tar.gz
# … with 30 more rows
```

Of course I do not want to type `download.file(url='https://this.is.url_number.tar.gz', destfile='files.tar.gz', method='curl')` 40 times for each url. How can I loop over all url's in column_1 using `download.file()`?

Comment: Do you have separate `destfile`

Comment: ideally destination of all files is in one downloads folder. i don't need to edit the name of the download for each loop

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way in a `for`loop

```
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))) {
    download.file(url = df$column_1[i], 
    destfile = paste0('files', df$column_ID_number[i], 
         '.tar.gz'), method = 'curl')
}
```

Comment: if I did have a corresponding `column_ID_number` for each file, how would I incorporate that number into the name of each download?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` -

```
Map(download.file, df$column_1, sprintf('file%d.tar.gz', seq(nrow(df))))
```

where `sprintf` is used to create filenames to save the file.